# Is there a real problem in this Retrospect duplicate of my hard drive?

Tags: windows-xp, ms-security-essentials, duplicate

I recently duplicated my XP "C" drive, using Retrospect.
When it finished, there were 6 errors. I checked the log and the 1st error referred to

Microsoft Security Essentials\Support\Applications.etl: Appears incomplete.

The other 5 errors referred to the Microsoft SQL Server.....\MSSQL\log_...trc: Appears incomplete.

Is this a problem that can be solved by reinstalling Microsoft Security Essentials? Or what else?   Any help appreciated, Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have now backed up the drive again, with no errors, so I guess everything is okay.

If I get no response in the next day or two, I will accept this as an answer, although I have no more information.